# How do I force a path to follow the same property for a variable number of steps

Tags: neo4j, cypher

- I am trying to find a path from *s*:start to *f*:finish.
- The nodes in between are a mesh of crossroads.
- The relationships between each nodes have two properties, ***name***(str) and ***steps***(int).
- When the path is traversed, ***name*** must be repeated ***steps*** times before other name is used.

EXAMPLE: from node *a* I have 3 outgoing relationships ({x,2}{y,3}{**z**,4}). To get to *b*, the path may only use **z** if there are 4 (no more, no less) **z** between *a* and *b*.

Comment: Is it possible to combine the paths? e.g. get from A to B in 4*z steps, and then with B specified as {r, 5}, get from B to C in 5*r, so it means we can get from A to C in 4*z + 5*r ?

Comment: yes, precisely that.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible in plain Cypher due the path combination... so you have to make your own procedure with the Traversal API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition on the path that you get back.

```
MATCH path = (start:Label {id:$id})-[rels*..20]-(end)
WHERE all(idx IN range(0,size(rels)-2)
      WHERE all(r2 IN rels[idx+1..(idx + (rels[idx]).steps)] WHERE (rels[idx]).name = r2.name))
RETURN path
```

It will be much easier and more efficient in Java in a custom traverser/expander than in Cypher though.

See: @maxdemarzi's blog: https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/09/04/flight-search-with-the-neo4j-traversal-api/

Comment: Thank you very much. The Traversal API really seems the best way to go indeed.